# React.js - CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [AWS - Lambda - API GATEWAY]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a react client application that sends form data to `AWS API Gateway`.
When I test the API with `Postman` everything works fine, but when I use `Axios` in react, an error is shown in the console :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I enabled CORS in API Gateway methods, also my `AWS Lambda function` has `Lambda proxy integration`, but apparently it didn't solve the issue.

How can i fix this ? Thanks in advance.

----- UPDATE -------

Based on the comments, here is the build function for the response I'm sending from the `Lambda function` :

```
const buildResponse = (statusCode, body) => {
return {
    statusCode : statusCode,
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(body)
}
}
```

Where I make the call :

```
const get = async () => {
const params = {
  TableName: dynamoTable
}
const all= await scanDynamoRecords(params, []);
const body = {
  data: all
}
return buildResponse(200, body);
}
```

Comment: Which origins are you allowing?

Comment: @StefanN I'm allowing all origins :  `"*"`

Comment: Great! Can you show the code pls?

Comment: @StefanN the question has been updated sir, thank you.

Comment: Check if your API gateway is forwarding the access control header? It is not received on the client side based on the error message

Comment: @StefanN who can I check for that ?

Comment: Then pls add http-allow-method header (at least options, post and get) and also in you origins header it is always better to list all the origins. For example, add `http://localhost:3001` instead of using the *

Comment: did you deployed your `API Gateway` after enabling CORS?

Comment: @SagarDarekar Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading about `CORS` and consulting with a professional, response headers must be updated to the following in order to fix the problem :

```
headers : {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"      
    }
```

Of course, `CORS` must be enabled on API Gateway for each method used.

Comment: why would the order matter here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable credentiels for axios like this:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```